# Jest cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createRoot')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs, vite

I am trying to learn testing and am stumped on this error. My project uses Vite Typescript.

I am getting this error when I running my tests with jest (react testing library).

```
Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createRoot')

   8 | export const queryClient = new QueryClient();
   9 |
> 10 | ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
     |          ^
  11 |   <React.StrictMode>
  12 |     <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
  13 |       <App />
```

This is my test that I am trying to even get set up.

```
test("it should trigger form errors when description and amount is not filled", async () => {
  // arrange
  // render(<AddExpenditure />);
  render(
    <div id="root">
      <AddExpenditure />
    </div>
  );

  screen.debug();
});
```

However, when I just plug in my other components to the render function, this error does not appear and those tests pass. Do you know why/a fix for this?

**jsconfig**

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
export default {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css)$": "./mocks/styleMock.js",
  },
};
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```